# Is a settlement with 50,000 inhabitants a town or a city?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

I wonder when a place deserves to be called a city.
Suppose that we have a settlement which has 50,000 persons. Is that a town or a city?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether an urban area is designated a town or a city depends on several factors.

The first is the size of the population: According to: Settlement Hierarchy, Wikipedia:

> > The population of a city is over 100,000 people up to 300,000. Large town – a large town has a population of 20,000 to 100,000. Town – a town has a population of 1,000 to 20,000. Village – a village is a human settlement or community that is larger than a hamlet but, smaller than a town.

Differencebetween.net points out that:

> > Cities cover a wider area than towns and as cities advance, they may sometimes incorporate or merge with surrounding areas. Towns on the other hand do not generally expand into other areas in the same way as cities.

But the most important factor is the local naming convention.

In the United Kingdom, city status is granted by the monarch.
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_status_in_the_United_Kingdom)

In much of early Christian Europe, city status depended on the presence of a cathedral as a statement of the bishop's authority. In 16th century England:

> > After founding the Church of England in 1534 Henry VIII created 6 cathedral towns in the 1540's and gave them all city status by letters patent. This created the association between having a cathedral and city status. The other towns with cathedrals at the time also became to be considered cities since "time immemorial".

(http://www.lovemytown.co.uk/Cathedrals/Cathedrals.htm)

So, in answer to your question, your 50,000 strong community is unlikely to be considered a city unless some authority has declared it to be one.

Comment: Very nice and useful answer. Thanks so much. But why is city only up to 300,000? My Chisinau, which is the capital of Moldova, has about 700,000 persons. What is it, isn't it a city?

Comment: The source goes on to place bigger urban groupings in categories such as *large city, metropolis, conurbation and megalopolis*. Other sources may offer different definitions.

Comment: This is all very interesting, but you could still call places like London, New York, Los Angeles, or Buenes Aires a "city" and no one would correct you.

Comment: @J.R. I'm in full agreement. It just a question of whose definition. As it happens, the little town near which I live in Portugal is officially a city but this would come as a surprise to most visitors.